# How To Find Android Google Play Services Version

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, google-play-services

I'm working on an android project which requires the use of google maps. I've been reading tutorials, and I have to add this to the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

The thing is, I don't know what number to substitute the "@integer/google_play_services_version" with.

If anyone knows what I should enter there, and how to obtain that integer value, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is no need to subsitute. The value `@integer/google_play_services_version` takes care of it. Just make sure you have the latest Google Play Services library which is updated.

You can find it under `google-play-services_lib>res>values>version.xml` if you wish to add the number rather than `@integer/google_play_services_version`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">4030500</integer>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was useful; however, my map still doesn't show. lol

Comment: @user3184786 in which case you should post the relevant code or debug yourself. Your problem may not be related to this or may be altogether a different issue. lol :)

Answer (score 15):

Here is [the official guide for setting up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) in your project.

**FYI,** you could find the version number in this folder:

```
~\android-studio\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 7):

Error you have mentioned is maybe because of not adding Google play services lib as library of your project do the following.

1. Select File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
2. Select Browse, enter 
   /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib, and click Open.
   3.Select Copy projects into workspace and click Finish.

Mark Google Play services as a library: Right-click the google-play-services_lib project, and choose Properties > Android. Tick the Is Library option.

Right click on your project -> go to properties -> click android -> click add button -> click google_play_services_lib -> ok -> apply -> ok clean your project 
this will remove your error

Answer (score 6):

If you are using **gradle** just make sure you have the updated google play services version (downloaded using SDK manager) and put this in your project module dependency section:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
 In general it is not a good practice to remove the concrete version of the source you are compiling against.

Comment: whence you resync with gradle
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
will turn green

Answer (score 1):

I was in a case where I had to use the Froyo version of the Google Play Services, and that version doesn't require the tag. In fact, the XML entry google_play_services_version does not exist in the Froyo+ version of the Google Play Services library